# ORMLite OpenTransaction batch Insert & Getting back new Guids

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to use ServiceStack ORMLite to run this:

```
        using (var o = Conn.OpenDbConnection()) {
            using (var t = o.OpenTransaction()) {
              foreach(var item in items) o.Insert(item);
              t.Commit();
              //now, how do I get back the new item ids I have just inserted?
            }
        }
```

In the code, how do I get back the batch new Ids? Also noticed the non-batch version GetLastInsertId() only return a Long. What do I do when my Id type is a GUID? Thank you.

Also, while you are here, I would like to also ask, if `t.Commit();` fails an exception is thrown, is there a need there to call `t.Rollback();`? since the transaction is over anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **v4**, `db.Save()` automatically populates the AutoIncrement Id, e.g:

```
db.Save(item);
item.Id //populated with the auto-incremented id
```

Otherwise you can select the last insert id using:

```
var itemId = db.Insert(item, selectIdentity:true);
```

Here are [more examples showcasing OrmLite's new API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs).

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your help again mythz.